# How to define a Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I've got a question about how to define this really simple layout:

I'd like to use Relative Layouts but I'd need the B height to fill all the height that A leaves.

I'm trying to do a layout that suits for all the resolutions, so I cannot specify px or dp in the xml layout definition.

Ideally, I don't wanna use the wrap content property for height because B is a ListView.

Is there any solution at all?

Thanks

[Layout image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/39/layoutzn.png/)

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Please let us know what type of layout is A and B and changing the relative layout to linear should be a solution for you? Thank you!

Comment: My suggestion to you first go and read tutorials on www.developer.android.com then ask questions here....

Comment: @Cata: 
A - RelativeLayout
B - ListView

himanshu: I've been there lots of times.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/holder_a"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/holder_a" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout >
  <A fixed height /> 
  <B layout_below=a fill_parent />
</RelativeLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I'm trying to do a layout that suits for all the resolutions"

Then you should do more than one XML file, else it's impossible to have  1 perfect layout for all devices, except Height of A is fixed

Comment: Totally agreed, and even more when you do for tablets landscape and portrait ... X)

Comment: hahaha, yes, but as the size of the screen is different, the use of the space should be different, meaning another XML etc... a wildfire should display informations like a Galaxy S2 (as facebook is doing)

Comment: Well, not necessarily.. If it's a ListView, you'd see less rows in Wildfire.. that's all..

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the layout that you want:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></LinearLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can replace the inner `LinearLayout` with anything you want.

Comment: I'm trying to use RelativeLayout instead of LinerLayout as they suggest..so this wouldn't fit my need, even though it totally works..

Comment: First line here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html

I do use now too many nested linearlayouts..

Comment: That's a suggestion - not a general rule. Personally I avoid using `RelativeLayout`, because it's so easy to screw up the positioning of things and you end up searching for that one little bug for hours. In the end it comes down to personal preference. My suggested layout will display what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use android:layout_weight

<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="100"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="70" >

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/widget32" android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="30" android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That wouldn't fit my needs because I need the 'A' layout to be always exactly 60dp tall, not 70%.
Moreover, if you specify the weight the android:layout_height must be "0dp"